# How to add column in drupal content list table?

Tags: content-management-system, drupal-6

In my drupal site I want to sort content on the date posted basis is there any way to do it?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible with core but if you are willing to install new modules on your site (or if you already have them), [Views](http://drupal.org/project/views) and [Views Bulk Operations (VBO)](http://drupal.org/project/views_bulk_operations) will get you a long way ahead. VBO even comes with default views that are designed to replace the standard admin listings.

Comment: I dont want to do the content bulk operation instead of that I just want to add the column in table which shows a content

Comment: Well in essence the listing you have in your image is a bulk operations listing. VBO just makes it more customisable, you can add any columns you want in the table.

Comment: hey thanks for your answer but if you see my image properly its admin panel content table.I just wanted to know whether it is possible to add column in core content table?

Comment: No it is not possible. But you can get identical, or even improved, functionality by using the VBO default views as a starting point. Sorry for being so concise.